# PGP's -cw option in GnuPG

Tags: pgp, gnupg

I am new to PGP and am going through the book.  I have GnuPG on my OS X.  I've been through the man pages for GnuPG and to encrypt files the following is instructed: https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html.  But this is not the same as what -cw option does in PGP.  Can anyone explain how to execute -cw in GnuPG as it is executed in the book?  Thanks.

Comment: Which book? The manual? Can you add snippets from the manual to the question so that the question contains the relevant information? Right now it is difficult to understand what you are asking without reading the web page.

Comment: I read this: http://bit.ly/1Ox9y0h.  But it did not work in GnuPG.  See below answer for a great explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pgp -cw` symmetrically encrypts a file (using a passphrase that the user is prompted for) and subsequently securely deletes the old one.

`pgp -c` (symmetric encryption) is performed using `gpg --symmetric` or the shorthand `gpg -c` (which is actually compatible to the old PGP syntax). If you want to enforce IDEA, use the option `--cipher-algo IDEA` or enforce PGP 2.6 compatiblity using `--pgp2`. Use either:

```
gpg --pgp2 -c file
gpg --cipher-algo IDEA --symmetric file
```

Secure deletion (`-w` flag in PGP 2.6.2) is not offered by GnuPG, fall back to the tools offered by your platform instead. OS X already ships `srm` (secure remove), for Linux you could use `wipe` (probably needs to be installed first). There are also lots of other alternatives.

Comment: Ah wow, this is loads of help.  I understand the answer to my question very clearly!  Thanks.  The other bits will have to be studied.  But the theory behind your explanation is awesome.